# Visa Approved at German Consulate with AXA-Schengen Europe Travel insurance?

Tags: insurance, schengen-visas

So it seems that AXA-Schengen Europe Travel insurance might not specify the split between different benefits. They claim that they follow the Schengen policy for insurance. Did anyone get their Schengen Visa approved at the Germany consulate while having AXA-Schengen Europe Travel insurance ?

Comment: My mother just got a Shenghen visa in German Mission in San Francisco with very similar travel insurance which also did not have the split.